# How to reset some Ruby Gem files without git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have made some modifications to some gem files that's not tracked by git. How do I reset the gem files to it's used version in console (with bundler?) ?

I'm also using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uninstall the gem

```
gem uninstall gem-name
```

And then do a

```
bundle install
```

should be the easiest solution

Comment: The formatting on this is a little messed up, but you do have the right answer here.

Comment: Thanks, might it be correct to make it a one line? `gem uninstall gem-name & bundle install` ? I actually did uninstall install of the gem (instead of using bundler)